# set JavaScript variable in another page

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently learning JavaScript and PHP, and I came across a simple problem .
I have a script file which collects some certain data , and I can save it to a variable . what I'm struggling with is to open another page (.PHP) and set the collected data into a `textarea` tag I have in that page . So for recap ,I click on send , the script collects data ,opens second page and puts it into the `textarea` I created for it.

```
document.getElementById('getJSON').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var survey_schema =formBuilder.actions.getData('json'); //the variable i want to send
    alert (survey_schema); // just test alert to check data

   //some code should be here (any help ??)
});
```

any help is appreciated.
thank you in advance

Comment: You don't need javascript to do so.You can use a session to do it with php

Comment: @destr0id i don't think you can assign a JavaScript variable to a PHP variable

Comment: You can use ajax to send data using post or get request and grab that data from php

Comment: @destr0id Ajax is pretty difficult for me right now , i'm still at early stages of learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` that in a kind of shared memory for the browser:

> The localStorage and sessionStorage properties allow to save key/value
> pairs in a web browser.

```
var yourObj = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage in first page with a custom key
localStorage.setItem('KeyObject', JSON.stringify(yourObj));

// Retrieve the object from storage in other page based on key
// Note that also you can send key as queryString
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('KeyObject');

//convert to josn
var json = JSON.parse(retrievedObject)

console.log(json);
```

Comment: doesn't that make any issues in the future if i put the website on webserver ??

Comment: Actually you store some data in it. Am I right?

Comment: yeah i store some data in it then collect it with some other to go to a database . it temporary

Comment: Ok there is no need to worry about it. But when you don't need the data you can remove it by : `localStorage.removeItem("KeyObject");`

Comment: i'm still trying to implement it , but it just doesn't work . on the second page nothing happens. i added a small script inside the html it doesn't run

Comment: You know I have lot's of page that work with this idea. You can log (`console.log`) the value on the second page and see the value passed correctly:
`var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('KeyObject');var json = JSON.parse(retrievedObject)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235023/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-karzan-nawzad).